# How do I restrict the type of characters that can be used at registrations?

Tags: 7, users

I want to disallow the use of spaces and all symbols except "_".

Comment: Are you looking for a module that allows that, or how to do that within a custom module?

Comment: Most importantly, for what do you want to disallow the use of such characters?

Comment: I want to be be able to generate a seo friendly URL with there user name.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you said in your comment, you should just use [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto). Pathauto allows you to remove special characters from user/node/taxonomy URLs; if someone's username is 'hey$3#@", you could make their user profile URL http://yourdomain.com/user/hey3.

Comment: I agree; generating a SEO friendly URL doesn't mean to limit the characters used for the usernames. To notice that in case of conflict, Pathauto will add a character to make the URL unique.